Default to deny in iptables using Docker
I've been looking into tightening up firewall restrictions on Docker hosts and I'm having fits with Docker's default iptables behavior. To make this question as simple as possible. imagine the following scenario:

A default Docker installation with a single container that exposes a single port using the host network (e.g. port 12345).
An additional iptables rule is needed to block any incoming port that is not part of a container.

Setting Docker's vagaries to the side for a moment, this could be handled simply with the following:
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP

Docker of course complicates everything, but I would like to approximate this behavior. Any help would be much appreciated!

I quote "By default, for both IPv4 and IPv6, the daemon blocks access to ports that have not been published."
By default, iptables block any port that is not in use by docker container or host. For example, your docker container is exposing port 12345. In this case, only port 12345 will be allowed through iptables, and the rest will be blocked. This means that no further action is required from you since iptables is already locked down (Unless you require advanced features, which you might not need after all).
In my humble opinion, docker daemon simplifies the configuration of iptables rules between the host and containers. Docker daemon handles the iptables rules behind the scenes. The involves the creation of firewall rules (when docker container is run) and the deletion of firewall rules (when docker container is killed).
Reference - https://docs.docker.com/engine/network/packet-filtering-firewalls/
